# Какое качество фронтальной камеры смартфона является более/менее хорошим?

Tags: камера, разрешение

Подскажите, какое качество фронтальной камеры смартфона является более/менее хорошим. Приведите разные разрешения (в Мп) и и их оценки. В смысле качества - какое количество мегапикселей для каких целей подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

720p достаточно для видеочата, планерок в zoom. Для фотографий себя в инстаграм 1080p. Для зарабатывания денег в приватных чатах лучше поискать камеру получше и с поддержкой hdr

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, то их можно задать с помощью кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Также, чтобы привлечь больше внимания к вопросу, можно [объявить награду](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/838846)

Comment: какой вопрос такой и ответ)

Comment: Вопрос явно не по теме StackOverflow.

Comment: @eri я имел ввиду градацию по Мпикс - 0-5Мпикс, 5-10Мпикс и т.д.

Comment: 1М, 2М и 5+М соответственно

Comment: @eri что такое 1М, 2М и 5+М? что за обозначения?

Comment: мегапиксели, вы ж просили)

Comment: @eri в смысле качества - какое количество мегапикселей для каких целей подходит?

Comment: ну ещё качество с Мп иногда не сходятся. а по Мп. а так да

Comment: @eri а Мп - что это за характеристика? как от нее зависят другие параметры смартфоны (и какие параметры)?

Comment: разные разрешения (в Мп)...)))